# Rails 4: Devise redirection issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using devise gem for my Rails app.
Everything was working fine on staging server. But recently I updated my **secret_key_base** value on the staging. From that point the following problem is arising.

Whenever I log in it works. But after some time the same login doesn't works and shows:

```
Redirected to https://example.com/ 
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
```

And then after when I change the **secret_key_base** value on the staging, everything works as expected and no error pops up.

But the above behaviour repeat after some random interval of time. 
Any help! 
Thanx

**UPDATED**
User Model

```
devise(*%i[
    database_authenticatable omniauthable registerable recoverable rememberable
    trackable validatable  ],
    omniauth_providers: %i[ facebook ] )
```

Comment: Can you paste your user model or the model where devise is applied?

Comment: @ChetanMehta I have updated my code